# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]:

Tags: joomla2.5

`Joomla 2.5.8` when i try to get to my web appeared this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::_*construct() [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse
>   time string ([) at position 0 ([): Unexpected character' in
>   D:\Hosting\11017096\html\pro\v2\v2\libraries\joomla\utilities\date.php:121
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\Hosting\11017096\html\pro\v2\v2\libraries\joomla\utilities\date.php(121):
>   DateTime->*_construct('[', Object(DateTimeZone)) #1
>   D:\Hosting\11017096\html\pro\v2\v2\libraries\joomla\factory.php(557):
>   JDate->__construct('[', 'UTC') #2
>   D:\Hosting\11017096\html\pro\v2\v2\libraries\joomla\html\html.php(712):
>   JFactory::getDate('[', 'UTC') #3 [internal function]: JHtml::date('[',
>   'd F Y') #4
>   D:\Hosting\11017096\html\pro\v2\v2\libraries\joomla\html\html.php(222):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #5
>   D:\Hosting\11017096\html\pro\v2\v2\libraries\joomla\html\html.php(135):
>   JHtml::call(Array, Array) #6
>   D:\Hosting\11017096\html\pro\v2\v2\modules\mod_sp_smart_slider\tmpl\magazine\view.php(66):
>   JHtml::_('date', '[', 'd F Y') #7 D:\Ho in
>   D:\Hosting\11017096\html\pro\v2\v2\libraries\joomla\utilities\date.php
>   on line 121

this is the line

Date.php 121

```
parent::__construct($date, $tz);
```

what i have to do?

Comment: What is at line 66 of `modules\mod_sp_smart_slider\tmpl\magazine\view.php`? It looks like the call to JHtml there is not formatted properly.

Comment: Line 65 <div class="sp-smart-date"> 
Line 66    <?php echo JHtml::_('date',$val['date'], JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3')); ?>

Comment: Is there a problem? I have no idea what to do

Comment: Please update to the newest Joomla, 2.5.11 because 2.5.8 has security holes. So maybe this is also already fixed in the newest version